# Integrate Unit test into Visual Studio Express 2008

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Is it possible to integrate any unit test framework into VS2008 express?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to do TDD in express versions of visual studio(eg VB Express)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258055/best-way-to-do-tdd-in-express-versions-of-visual-studioeg-vb-express)

Answer (score 1):

[NUnit](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/setting-up-nunit-for-c-unit-testing-with-visual-studio-c-express-2008/)

(Google is your friend.)

Edit: A very similar question: [Best way to do TDD in express versions of visual studio(eg VB Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258055/best-way-to-do-tdd-in-express-versions-of-visual-studioeg-vb-express)