# How to make a .dll and run it with NUnit?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, visual-studio-express

I'am totally new to Windows Store App programming, 
so i'am also new to Visual Studio Express.

My goal is to test a simpple class method.
As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424229/unit-testing-in-visual-c-sharp-2010-express) the Express version do not have any built-in Unit testing.
In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907842/how-to-install-nunit-plugin-in-visual-studio-2013-express), Rafal provides a [solution](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-execute-invoke-nunit-from-visual.html).

I exactly did it like described, so my external tools look like this:

[image]

When i execute it (Tools --> "Execute NUnit"), Nunit starts and the Gui of NUnit appears. But suddenly this exception occurs:

[image]

And in Exception Details:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException...

   at NUnit.Util.ProjectService.WrapAssembly(String assemblyPath)

   at NUnit.Util.ProjectService.ConvertFrom(String path)

   at NUnit.Util.ProjectService.LoadProject(String path)

   at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadProject(String filePath, String configName)
```

My project folder has this structure:

[image]

The test classes are in "WebTest.Shared".

I think i need a .dll to run in NUnit as mentioned by Jon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/258075/2281606). 
So, how can I make a dll out of my project to run it with NUnit?
Can anyone guide me through this problem? (Please step by step)

**EDIT:**

**After i worked in ChrisM idea, the exception stll arises without "${BinDir}${TargetName}.dll/run" block (the exception details are the same as before):**

[image]

**EDIT No. 2:**

I have set those values:

*Title:* Execute NUnit

*Command:* D:\Path\To\NUnit\bin\nunit.exe

*Arguments:* $(BinDir)$(TargetDir)$(TargetExt)/run

*Initial directory:* $(BinDir)

**EDIT No. 3:**

After closing and reopening VS Express
i got this new Exception:
[image: newException]

And in NUnit Exception Details:

System.ApplicationException: Unable to find test in assembly

System.ApplicationException...

**EDIT No. 4**

Here is my test class (StringUtilitiesTest.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using WebappTest.Shared.Utilities;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace WebappTest.UnitTest


{
    [TestFixture]
    public class StringUtilitiesTest
    {

        [Test]
        public void TransferFunds()
        {

            Assert.AreEqual("Hello", StringUtilites.getString("Hello"));

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In external Tools:

Have you tried replacing the curly braces {} in the argument box with normal ones ()?

Comment: Can you please post the content of the "Argumente" field?

Comment: hmm... I don't know what is causing your problem. From what you stated so far, I am guessing that NUnit can not find the Assembly containing your tests because for some reason the visual studio environment variables ( e.g. $(BinDir) ) are not working or contain wrong information. 
If I am right entering the absolute path to the assembly containing your tests ( webappTest.shared if I got you right ) into the arguments should make it work at least. Can you try that?

Comment: Looks like there is an attribute missing in your test class. Can you post the test class here as well?

Comment: That looks correct. I'm afraid I've got no further idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2017 Express (the final express version) includes the test explorer. Add the NUnit3TestAdapter NuGet to your project, and the test explorer should discover your tests.